# Parse.com channel must start with letter

Tags: ios, parse-platform, channel, pfuser

I am trying to get my app that uses Parse.com to allow you to subscribe to a user.  However, 'channels' in `PFInstallation` requires that all channels start with a letter only, and not have spaces.  However, Parse.com handles all the creation of objectIds for users when they login, and sometimes, they create an objectId that starts with a number.  How can I properly fix this so that my app will work properly?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't put ObjectIDs inside the `channels` property. You should store the information about the subscriptions in another property (or inside a join-table, see [Relations Guide](https://parse.com/docs/relations_guide)).

In order to push you can then use a query to determine the targets, as described [here](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending-queries/iOS).

Comment: I'm doing it this way so that one user can subscribe to another user, and get notified when that person posts something new.  This is something that was suggested in the Parse AnyPic tutorial.  However, I must have missed the part that suggested to always add user_ at the beginning of the objectId, so that it would always make sure the channel starts with a letter.

Comment: You don't want to be modifying the "objectId" property yourself, ever. Just add another property and do the appropriate query to get your push's to work.

Comment: I'm not modifying anything at all for objectId, I can't even do that.  I'm simply copying the objectId into channel.